# mysql update rows in table after one of them is deleted

Tags: mysql, count, reset

So i'm developing a website which allows users to create a project A.K.A "guide" and then add steps to that created project.

**For example my steps table structure:**

```
------------------------------------
 |  id  |  projectid  |  stepOrder |
 |  1   |     103     |      1     |
 |  2   |     103     |      2     |
 |  3   |     103     |      3     |
 |  4   |     103     |      4     |
 |  5   |     104     |      1     |
 |  6   |     104     |      2     |
 |  7   |     104     |      3     |
 -----------------------------------
```

So as you can see this table has 3 fields: id, projectID (references project id in another table) and stepOrder. Now if the user decided to delete step 2 from 103 project we would be left with something like this:

```
 ------------------------------------
 |  id  |  projectid  |  stepOrder |
 |  1   |     103     |      1     |
 |  3   |     103     |      3     |
 |  4   |     103     |      4     |
 |  5   |     104     |      1     |
 |  6   |     104     |      2     |
 |  7   |     104     |      3     |
 -----------------------------------
```

As you can see since we deleted step 2 it now jumps from step 1 directly to step 3.But instead i need it to be like this:

```
 ------------------------------------
 |  id  |  projectid  |  stepOrder |
 |  1   |     103     |      1     |
 |  3   |     103     |      2     |
 |  4   |     103     |      3     |
 |  5   |     104     |      1     |
 |  6   |     104     |      2     |
 |  7   |     104     |      3     |
 -----------------------------------
```

So how can i achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps some sort of loop that is triggered automatically re-inputs data into stepOrder once there has been a record deletion?

Just an idea, not sure by any means if this way is the most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done application-side as a subsequent update:

```
DELETE FROM guide_steps WHERE id=?
UPDATE guide_steps SET stepOrder=stepOrder-1 WHERE stepOrder>? AND projectid=?
```

You can lock this inside a transaction to avoid one step being done without the other.

It's also possible to wrap this up in a trigger, but that's usually a bad idea as it can be complicated to maintain those, and it's easy to get "trigger happy".